# Usage of the phrase "The essential"

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

I have seen the word "essential" used in a phrase such as:

> The essential Shakespeare.

Is it also common to use the word "essential" in the following way?

> The essential for any artists

to mean "a must-have for artists" in order to advertise a product for artists?

Comment: In the first usage, _essential_ is an adjective. In the second, it is used as a noun (we call this _nominalization_.) It is idiomatic to use the plural _the essential**s**_ and the singular _artist_ in constructions like yours: _The essentials for any artist._

Answer (score 1):

> The Essential Shakespeare

This particular use of "essential" is probably limited to titles of one sort or another.  It goes along with other words like "Complete" and "Beginning" and "Bible" and various others:

> "The Complete Chicken Cookbook"
>
> "Beginning Python: From Novice to Professional"
>
> "The Flavor Bible: The Essential Guide to Culinary Creativity, Based on the Wisdom of America's Most Imaginative Chefs"

All of these are real book titles (although not necessarily best-sellers).  Anyway it's  not a structure you'd use in a well-written sentence -- unless, of course, you're referring to the work with that title.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `essential` is just an adjective near `Shakespeare`.

In the second case, the full sentence could be like:

> The essential [thing, idea, tool...] for any artists...

Therefore, in this second case, `essential` behaves like a noun, absorbing the meaning of the missing word. If the noun would *not* be missing, `essential` would be a plain adjective, just like the one near Shakespeare.